# How do I set a transparent background for the sections Index Bar in a UITableView?

Tags: ios, swift

How do I set a transparent background for the `sections index bar` in a `UITableView`?

I've tried:

```
tableView.sectionIndexBackgroundColor = .clearColor()
```

but the bar gets a light grey background

**EDIT**
I've tried to change background color of the tableview but it doesn't seem to influence.

```
  tableView.backgroundView = UIView.init()
  tableView.backgroundColor = .blackColor() // tried .clearColor() too.
```

**EDIT2**

```
  tableView.sectionIndexBackgroundColor = UIColor(white: CGFloat(1.0), alpha: CGFloat(0.5)) // change the alpha and check once
```

I've also tried a color with alpha values. I can make the background semi-transparent (see line code above). But if I set alpha to 0.0 to make it completely transparent, I get again the light grey background.

Comment: What's the background color of the table?

Comment: @FahriAzimov I've added the answer to my question

Comment: Use a tableViewCell for header section or a view with transparent background. By default the table Section Headers have a light gray color.

Comment: How about using custom index bar for table view? Like this one: https://github.com/gdavis/GDIIndexBar

Comment: @FahriAzimov I would prefer to not change code in my project just to make this small change. Is it really not possible to have transparent background for index bars using native iOS APIs?

Answer (score 0):

`tableView.sectionIndexBackgroundColor = .clear` works perfect
[image: here's example]

Answer (score 0):

For swift 4.2 you must set viewBackground for your section and for that view set background color.

> class CommonSection: UITableViewHeaderFooterView {   static let
>   lightSectionColor = UIColor.gray.withAlphaComponent(0.005)
>        func setup(title: String, sectionColor: UIColor? = nil) {
>       textLabel?.text = title
>       textLabel?.font = UIFont.preferredFont(forTextStyle: .largeTitle)
>
> ```
> guard let color = sectionColor else { return }
>
> self.backgroundView = Init(value: UIView()) {
>   $0.backgroundColor = color
> }   } }
> ```

Note: Init just shortcut for initializing elements.